# Why my array parameter not in POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In laravel 5.7 / jquery 3 app I make saving of array of data and fail as in console of my browser I see that with submitting of the form
only _token parameter is sent in POST request:

```
let todos_count = $("#todos_count").val()
// alert( "saveTodoDialog todos_count::"+var_dump(todos_count)  +"  csrf_token::"+csrf_token )

let todosList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < todos_count; i++) {
    let todoItem = []
    todoItem['modified'] = $("#modified_" + i).val();
    todoItem['todo_text'] = $("#todo_text_" + i).val();
    todoItem['todo_priority'] = $("#todo_priority_" + i).val();
    todoItem['todo_completed'] = $("#todo_completed_" + i).val();
    alert("todoItem::" + var_dump(todoItem))
    todosList[todosList.length] = todoItem
}

console.log("todosList::")
console.log(todosList)
alert(todosList.length + "todosList::" + var_dump(todosList))

let href = "/admin/save-todo-page";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: href,
    data: {"_token": csrf_token, "todosList": todosList},
    success: function (response) {
        popupAlert("Todo items were saved successfully !", 'success')
    },
    error: function (error) {
        popupErrorMessage(error.responseJSON.message)
    }
});
```

My todosList array is correctly filled :

[image]

but it is not POST requestr. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript, as opposed to PHP, has a very strict behaviour for arrays in that they are **always** numerically indexed.

In your code you have:

```
let todoItem = []
todoItem['modified'] = $("#modified_" + i).val();
```

This is not allowed because you have an array but try to use it as an object. This will just create custom properties on the array object but will not actually add anything to the underlying array. This should be apparent in the console where your `todosList` array is an array of 3 arrays of length 0.

You can get this to work by doing:

```
let todosList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < todos_count; i++) {
    let todoItem = {
        modified: $("#modified_" + i).val(),
        todo_text: $("#todo_text_" + i).val(),
        todo_priority: $("#todo_priority_" + i).val(),
        todo_completed: $("#todo_completed_" + i).val()
    }; //Object initialiser
    todosList.push(todoItem);
}
```

The rest of the code should work as is